# A value of type 'Iterable<Transactions>' can't be returned from the function '_recentTransactions' because it has a return type of 'List<Transactions>

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i have a problem with my dart code when i add where function it gives me this error   A value of type 'Iterable' can't be returned from the function '_recentTransactions' because it has a return type of 'List

```
  final List<Transactions> _transactionsList = [

  ];
  List<Transactions> get _recentTransactions{
    return _transactionsList.where((element) => {

    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call `toList()` it is in the Iterable class:

```
List<Transactions> get recentTransactions {
  return _transactionsList.where((element) {
    return true // or whatever;
  }).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your return value as a `List<Transactions>`:

```
List<Transactions> get recentTransactions {
  return _transactionsList.where((element) {
    //...
  }) as List<Transactions>;
}
```